# Which http request headers are required for client?

Tags: http, client, httprequest, request-headers

Which of the http request headers are required for a client to get the correct response from server?
Does it depend on server back-end?

I've come up with situations in  which setting all request headers(just like browser does) gave me improper responses and i had to cross some out.

If all request headers are required, does it mean http helper libraries in programming languages set some default values? If not, is there a better solution than error-and-trail?

Comment: "*setting all request headers(just like browser does) gave me improper responses*". That should not be the case. Which headers were you setting?

Comment: User Agent, Content-Type (in GET requests)

Comment: Actually, only the `Host` request header is enough AND required to receive a proper answer from the server. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host).

Comment: If it is the ONLY required header, why browsers add at least 4 or 5 headers? what about Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded in posting data back to server?

Comment: Well, not all requests are sent through a browser. You can use a simple cmd interface (or terminal on Mac) to send a request to a server. If you do this and pass only the Host header, then you will certainly receive a proper answer, consisting of multiple response headers. I just wanted to evidentiate this core principle.

Comment: Of course, between the browsers and the servers takes place a much complexer communication, based on the type of request, the requested resource, the message body, the settings defined by the developer (meta's for example), the default headers' handling/setting of the browser, etc. The base principle is, that the server gives a response based only on what it is requested to send back.